# How to play the videos of a youtube playlist in loop?

Tags: android, video, android-youtube-api

I am playing a Youtube playlist using the youtube api. But while playing the last video of the playlist the player doesn't play first video.

I have googled a lot around and also check for all the youtube api but couldn't find any solution.

I'm using **YouTubePlayerSupportFragment** to play the video playlist. How can i set the loop variable to enable the loop feature.

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

    mplayer = player;
    final class MyPlaylistEventListener implements PlaylistEventListener{

        @Override
        public void onNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaylistEnded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrevious() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }  
    }

    MyPlayerStateChangeListener myPlayerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
    MyPlaylistEventListener myPlaylistEventListener = new MyPlaylistEventListener();
    player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(myPlayerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaylistEventListener(myPlaylistEventListener);
    player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.loadPlaylist("playlistID", videoIndex, 0);
    }
}`
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried editing the onPlaylistEnded() state in the listener you've created?

```
 @Override
    public void onPlaylistEnded() {

          player.loadPlaylist("playlistID", videoIndex, 0);
    }
```